# この薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。 Clarification on によっては

Tags: grammar, particle-は

I was reading Kanzen Master Bunpou 2kyuu and I got to this sentence:

> この薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。

I read the explanation and it's:

ある～の場合には＜（～によっては）が使われる＞

I looked up [How does は apply itself to によっては?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8095/how-does-%E3%81%AF-apply-itself-to-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF)

But I still do not understand how the meaning changes.

I think it means:

> Depending on this medicine side effects could manifest

I don't understand what is the point of adding は.
How does the sentence change?

I downloaded another version of the same book from a different source and the sentence is different.

> この薬はによっては副作用が出ることがあります。

Is this version better?

[image]

Comment: Quote from the accepted answer on your linked question:  `によって：means to change state or behaviour depending on something or according to something. It expresses variety and is often used with さまざまだ　and かえる.  によっては：pinpoints one outcome from a range of possible outcomes.`

Comment: Ok, But I want to know  what role は plays here.

Comment: So it the book saying that によっては is an abbreviation for 場合によっては?  

Because to me によっては in a sentence like that sounds like:
Talking about "depending on this medicine" side effect could come.  
or something like When talking about "depending on this medicine" specifically and not others, side effect could come. 
As if the presence of は after によっては makes a relative clause like this: [この薬によっては副作用が出る]>ことがあります。

Comment: ～によって/～により/～による/～によっては   接続:[名]+によって E意味:ある～の場合には<[～によっては]が使われる>  Ex. 1「 この薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。」Ex. 2 [宗教によってはにくを食べることが禁じられている。]

Comment: Why is it strange?

Comment: Ok, I don't want to ask too many question since I have already another one open. So I changed the title like you asked me. Thank you.

Comment: "この薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。" sounds unnatural. Does your textbook really say that? Is it not この薬によって or 薬によっては?

Comment: I downloaded from anothers source and in this one は is present after 薬.

Comment: ^ Wait, so it says この薬**は**によっては? It's grammatically incorrect...

Comment: Wait a second and I'll try to post an image.

Comment: Oh, it's 「この薬は、 **人**によっては」.

Comment: Oh yeah, how did I not see that Is beyond me.  
I am really sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (I'm told) from a textbook :

> ～によって　　/　　～により　　/　　～による　　/　　～によっては
>  接続:　　[名]+によって  
>  意味: 　　ある～の場合には 　　 <[～によっては]が使われる>
>
> - Ex. 1　　「 この薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。 」
> - Ex. 2　　「 宗教によっては肉を食べることが禁じられている。 」 <--- This one is fine.

I think **「 この薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。」 is a very strange sentence.

- Correct 1:　「 この薬によって副作用が出ることがあります。」 　== (By) using this drug,  side-effects may occur.
- Correct 2:　「 薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。」　 == Depending on the drug (used), side-effects may occur.
- Correct 3:　「 この薬は、場合によっては副作用が出ることがあります。」　 == This drug [ depending on the circumstances ] may cause side-effects.

So I think **「 この薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。」 is (a hybrid, a chimera) a very strange sentence, which a reviewer missed and didn't correct.

---

> - Ex. 2　　「 宗教によっては肉を食べることが禁じられている。 」 <--- This one is fine.
> - Correct 2:　「 薬によっては副作用が出ることがあります。」　 == Depending on the drug (used), side-effects may occur.

(Since Jp has no plural form, it's not explicit, but ...)  in these examples above, existence of plural [religions] and [drugs] is assumed.

It's like [Denpending on the drug(s) that you choose ...]

So it makes no sense to say:  この薬によっては ... -- because it's as if one has *already chosen* .

---

> I don't understand what is the point of adding は. How does the sentence change?

WA is for emphasis.  All these examples are possible without the WA.

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/168566/meaning/m0u/
>   に‐よっ‐て【に因って／に▽依って】
>
> ［連語］ 《格助詞「に」に動詞「よる」の連用形が付き、さらに接続助詞「て」の付いた「によりて」の音変化》
>
> [３]. その中のあるものについて、または、その中の一つ一つについていうと、の意を表す。
>
> - 「種類によって毒のあるものもいる」 <----- Apparently talking about snakes or spiders.
> - 「政治家によって主張は異なる」

Ahhh!  One question solved, another one born.  In this last example, it's very bad (or pretty bad) to insert a WA :

> **「政治家によっては主張は異なる」

Comment: So from what I undersand によっては does not filter out a single outcome from all the possible outcomes but it would be like: Talking about "depending on this medicine" side effect could come. or something like When talking about "depending on this medicine" specifically and not others, side effect could come. As if the presence of は after によっては makes a relative clause like this: [この薬によっては副作用が出る]>ことがあります。

Answer (score 1):

～によって means either:

1. depending on ～

   > 薬によって、副作用が出ることがあります。
   >    Depending on the drug, side effects may occur.
2. by ～; due to ～ (explicitly marks the origin of an action, [often used to avoid ambiguity](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37097/5010))

   > この薬によって、副作用が出ることがあります。
   >    By (taking) this drug, side effects may occur.

When は is added, ～によっては almost always means "depending on ～". Here は is a plain old topic marker. You know [many natural Japanese sentence require a topic marked with は](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1096/5010), and "depending on" usually deserves a topic marker in many sentences.

> 薬によっては、副作用が出ることがあります。
>     Depending on the drug, side effects may occur.

But can we say the following?

> **この**薬によっては、副作用が出ることがあります。

Well, this sentence would be okay when は is obviously used as a contrast marker:

> あちらの薬は安全です。でも、この薬によっては、副作用が出ることがあります。
>     That (another) drug is safe. But by this drug, side effects may occur.

Otherwise, I would say I seldom see the plain topic marker used at that position, and I feel the sentence in question is nearly incorrect. It looks like "Depending on *this* drug..." to me, and it makes little sense.