# 「によって」の意味と使い方についての質問です

Tags: translation

> 「。。。私は、人間が生得的に備えた「笑いの能力」はまず、新生児の微笑から顕在化すると考える。そして、その微笑が、人間関係の最初に位置するところの笑いと考えておきたいのである。
> この新生児微笑は、人**によって**はまったく問題にもされず、一種の生理的痙攣であると言う人がいる。」

（井上宏の『笑い学のすすめ』を参照しています。）

ここでは「によって」はどういう意味ですか？同じ使い方で例文を挙げてくれませんか？
I don't understand what the author is trying to say here 人**によって**はまったく問題にもされず

I tried comparing it to other sentences like

> 人々によって違います。
>
> 人間の行動による影響

But it doesn't make sense. Why does he use 「によって」 here?

教えてください

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「。。。私は、人間が生得的に備えた『笑いの能力』はまず、新生児の微笑から顕在化すると考える。そして、その微笑が、人間関係の最初に位置するところの笑いと考えておきたいのである。
>
> この新生児微笑は、人**によって**はまったく問題にもされず、一種の生理的痙攣であると言う人がいる。」

先ず確認しておきたいのは、前半の文章にあるように、作者はこの「新生児微笑」という理論を全面的に支持しているということです。

後半で述べているのは、この理論は決してすべての学者・専門家から同様に支持されているわけではなく、中にはそれを完全否定している人たちもいるということです。わかりますね？

この「～～によって（は）」は、「**問題となっているグループの中のひとつひとつ/ひとりひとりについて言うと**」という意味になります。「新生児微笑の理論」を支持する者と全く支持しない者がいると言っています。後者のグループには、「新生児微笑理論」を「一種の生理的痙攣」であると切り捨てていると作者は述べているのです。

同じ意味で「～～によって（は）」を使った例文をあげておきます。

> 「アメリカ合衆国では、州**によっては**赤信号で車が右折できるところがある。」
>
> 「この大学では、学生**によっては**毎日往復5時間以上かけて通学しています。」
>
> 「同じ地域の住民でも、人**によって**好きなラーメン店は全く異なります。」

いかがでしょうか？すべて、「グループ全体の中の一部はこうである」と言っているのがお分かりになりますか。

質問者さんは、この意味での「～～による」を、別の意味を持つもう一つの「～～による」と混同されているようです。

> 「人間の行動**による**影響」

こちらの「よる」は、「**物事が起きる原因**」を表しています。

例えば、

「人間**によって**環境が破壊される。」

「大雨**によって**家が流されてしまった。」

といった使い方をします。

Comment: かなりわかりやすい説明、本当にありがとうございました！例文などを読むと理解できました。

Answer (score 1):

> **人によっては**まったく問題にもされず、一種の生理的痙攣であると言う人がいる
>
> (Lit.)
>   **Depending on the person**, they may not even think of it as an issue, saying that it is a kind of physiological reflex
>
> (rendered more naturally)
>    **According to some people** it's not even worth noting because it's just a physiological reflex.
>   OR
>   **Some people** don't even consider it to be an issue, saying that it is a kind of physiological reflex

I think you are on the right track with `人々によって違います。` (btw, should just be `人によって違います。`) but note the は after によって this has a big impact on the meaning. It can make the difference between "depending on" and "according to" when thinking in English.

Related: [How does は apply itself to によっては?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8095/how-does-%E3%81%AF-apply-itself-to-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF)