# What does the に do in 表情から察するに?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, conjunctions

> その表情から察する**に**魔剣を所持している人は少ないみたいだ。

I'm having trouble figuring out what に does here. Does it have the same meaning as と?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's right. This kind of `に` won't always be replaceable with `と`, but in your case it basically is.

From [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB/):

> ［接助］活用語の連体形に付く。
>   **１** あとの叙述の前置きとして続ける意を表す。…と。…ところ。
>   「考えてみる**に**庶民のための政治は当分望めそうにない」

The `に` marks a lead-in to the main point which follows.

- その表情から察するに〜 *Judging from the expression…*
- 私が思うに〜 *The way I think of it…*
- 彼が言うに〜 *According to him…*