# Can について be used in the sense of "(judging) from"?

Tags: usage, word-usage

Can について be used in the sense of "judging from" and, if so, would the sentence "話し方について、あの男は昔先生だったはずです。" be correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, ～について does not mean "judging from ～". (I'm curious how you came up with this idea.)

I assume you want to say "Judging from his way of speaking, ..." You can use ～から判断すると, ～からすると, ～から言って, ～からすれば, ～から察すると, ～から察するに, etc.

> - 話し方から判断すると、あの男は昔先生だったはずです。
> - 話し方からすると、あの男は昔先生だったはずです。
> - 話し方から察するに、あの男は昔先生だったはずです。

Reference:

- [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: からすると/からすれば](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0-kara-suru-tokara-sureba/)
- [What does the に do in 表情から察するに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29418/5010)