# The meaning ところを見るに

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-に

> 僕らを待っているのではなさそうな**ところを見るに**、 まだ[回末]{うえまつ}[李花子]{りかこ}は外に出ていないのだろうか。

I've seen that に after conjugated verbs quite a few times now, but don't quite get what it means. It doesn't seem to a shortening of のに or ために.
Is this a case of ところを見ると? If so, why is the と being replaced by に?

What i've got is:

> Judging from the fact that (he/Kiyonosuke) doesn't seem to be waiting for us, I'd say Uematsu Rikako has yet to come out (of her house).

But that に always confuses me.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29418/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「に」 in this context is a conjunctive particle that connects a preface/introduction to a conclusion/opinion.

In meaning, 「に」=「と」in this sentence.  The difference is that using 「と」 would make it more informal.

The translation provided looks good.  The "judging from" part actually captures the nuance of this 「に」 well.

Comment: Do you have any sources where I can read up a little bit about this usage of に other than a j-j dictionary? I think I could learn a couple of things from that.