# The use of 様子を見る + に in this sentence

Tags: meaning, particle-に

[image]

でもあなたの様子を見るに
この件について何か心当たりがあるのでは

My understanding of "様子を見る" is akin to "wait and see" or "survey the situation"

So I took the whole sentence akin to "By having you survey the situation, concerning the case related some clue  may appear."

Most uses of あなたの様子を見る doesn't seem to use the に particulate some what is happening here. I assume the character may have omitted something?

Comment: Related or dup　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59276/45489