# What is non-past verb + に?

Tags: grammar

> あの慌てようを見るに、危ない落ち方をしたのだろう。

The context is that the speaker fell over and hit his head, and his mom screamed and ran over.

I think that it means something like "Seeing her panic, I guess it was a dangerous kind of fall", but what on earth is the に? I can't find anything about に attached to a verb except for には, but even if the は can be omitted, the meaning doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: Zero nominalization? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4489/30454

Comment: Duplicate/related: [Grammar behind 言うには](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82426/grammar-behind-%e8%a8%80%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af),  [What does the に do in 表情から察するに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29418/what-does-the-%e3%81%ab-do-in-%e8%a1%a8%e6%83%85%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e5%af%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab)