# Attack on Titan: What is もしくは doing in this comparision

Tags: meaning, sentence, anime, conjunctions

I saw this sentence in an episode of Attack on Titan

> ライナーができないと言うように**もしくは**ライナーでさえここで休まざるを得ない現状を鑑みるに

The speaker is referencing something that ライナー said they can't do

I don't understand why you would use **もしくは** in this comparison I thought **もしくは** meant A or B representing two different states but in this example the two states to me don't seem that different

My translation would be

> ライナーができないと言うように - As\like Reiner said I cant do it
>
> **もしくは** - Or
>
> ライナーでさえここで休まざるを得ない現状を鑑みるに - I need to keep in mind that in this situation even Reiner was forced to take a break

What am I missing? To me it feels off as the second state seems to "agree" with the first

Comment: Does this come from the manga? Anime? Or some other medium? What's said before and after?

Comment: Its from the anime and I didnt want to add to much info the line before is だが そもそも俺は
まともに巨人化できるのか？ and the line after 下手に
体力のない巨人を生み出せばほかの巨人に
やられちまうってことか？

Answer (score 1):

The context seems significant in this case. I *think* the lines mean something like:

> だが、そもそも俺はまともに巨人化できるのか？
> But am I even able to properly transform into a 巨人 to begin with?
>
> ライナーができないと言うように(なるかもしれない)
> Things will likely go as Reiner said, which means I will probably fail (if I try)
>
> もしくは
> or
>
> ライナーでさえここで休まざるを得ない現状を鑑みるに
> Judging from the fact that even Reiner has to take a break here
>
> 下手に体力のない巨人を生み出せばほかの巨人にやられちまうってことか？
> I will probably end up eaten by other 巨人 if I bungle it and transform into a weak 巨人

鑑みる**に** is explained in this answer:

[Grammar behind 言うには](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82426/30454)

And ライナーでさえここで休まざるを得ない現状を鑑みるに apparently connects with the following line, which is why context is important here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the story too well, but looking at [context](https://www.lingq.com/ja/learn-japanese-online/courses/599694/shingeki-no-kyojin-season-2-attack-on-3776765/), the two means different reasons for staying where they are.

What ライナー is saying できない looks like running away (from titans?) not just for Reiner, but for others including Eren. So the part means *as Reiner says it is impossible, or considering the current situation that even Reiner has to rest here* (we have no choice but to wait for the nightfall).

Comment: Pretty sure できない refers to 巨人化. 「そもそも今お前らは巨人になれん。そんな都合のいい代物じゃ ねぇのさ。体力は限られている。今はお前らの体を修復するので手いっぱいのようだ」

Comment: @EddieKal Probably. I thought the same at first, but somehow  巨人化できないあるいはライナーでさえここで休まざるをえない現状を考えれば  does not connect very well to me. I don't think the sentence is  thought through anyway.

Comment: Since Reiner mentions that it is impossible to run away (even by becoming a 巨人) and considering 単純 に 夜 に なる の を 待って る って こと か following the part, できない could refer to runaway (or both runaway and becoming a titan).