# には with plain form of verb

Tags: translation, particles, particle-に, particle-は, role-language

I'm trying to figure out what this sentence below means, but I'm having trouble with the には after the dictionary form of いる.

> もう１匹**居るには居る**んじゃが…。

I've read [Dictionary form of verb followed by に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27907/dictionary-form-of-verb-followed-by-%E3%81%AB), but my best attempt then becomes "In order for one creature to already exist, it exists, but...", which still doesn't quite make sense.

What is the function of には here? And what would be the best translation for this sentence? I believe that じゃ is 関西弁 for a state-of-being. Is this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would translate that as:

> Well, if you really insist, I do have one more.

Basically, the speaker does have one more, but is reluctant to mention it.

This form of には is mentioned [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/167736/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF/):

> （多く「…には…が」の形で、動詞や形容詞を繰り返して）一応その動作や状態は認めるが、それに関連して起こる動作や状態については関知したり容認したりしない意を表す。「推薦状は、書く―書くが、あまり期待しないでくれ」「涼しい―涼しいが、ちょっと冷えすぎる」
> (Often times in the form "…には…が", where you repeat a verb or adjective) It means when you will admit to some behavior or condition but any result of that condition or behavior you do not accept or tolerate.

One of the examples given in the definition is:

> 推薦状は、書くには書くが、あまり期待しないでくれ
> I'll write a recommendation letter for you, but don't expect anything
> fantastic.

By using the `には` in the above, the speaker indicates that they will write the recommendation letter, however at the same time they indicate how they are reluctant to do it perhaps because they don't have confidence in writing it.

> I believe that じゃ is 関西弁 for a state-of-being

This form of `じゃ` is a form of [老人語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E). In short, often in anime and manga, `じゃ` is a stereotypical way of speaking to indicate the person is elderly. It is the same meaning as `だ` in standard dialect.

Comment: Not just anime and manga, but basically all Japanese fiction.

Comment: Or Hiroshima dialect.

Comment: I've just realized that the 役割語 could also apply to country bumpkins, but there's no guarantee this is 役割語 at all; the sentence is too short.