# What is the grammar of にはいた?

Tags: grammar

> リビングにいた面々が、ぱちぱちと手を叩きながら口々に言う。制服を着た少女たちが、照れくさそうに頰を染めた。ーーまあ一部、狂三の言葉に青筋を立てる真那のような例外もいる**にはいた**のだけれど。

(Date a live, book 22)

What is the grammar of the bold part? Can we omit it?

Comment: Duplicate? [には with plain form of verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29886/43676)

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you. I didn’t know this 〜には〜けれど was a fixed pattern. So why is the sentence not いるにはいるのだけれど? The tense of the second いる can be past tense?

Comment: This link seems to explain the structure. https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=20757