# Understanding わけでなし

Tags: grammar, parsing, i-adjectives, particle-し

> 操縦桿を握るパイロットに告げた。普段八五区外に飛ばす機会など全くない、偵察機での長距離飛行を許可されて楽しげな顔なじみのパイロットは気軽く頷く。
>
> 「了解です、大佐。……ですが、その辺りは規則では輸送の連中の飛行禁止区域ですよ？」
>
> 「何、問題ないだろう。競合区域まで入る**わけでなし**、それにこの速度なら着くのは夜だ。〈レギオン〉どもは動かんよ」

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

Is the わけでなし the same as わけではないし?

Comment: Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3080/45489

Comment: I suppose what Eddie Kal says is right, but practically わけ + {で,では,でも} + {なし、ないし} all sound the same to me (with slight difference added by は or も).

Answer (score 1):

No, more like わけでない, related to わけではない, less the contrast marker. It does **not** include the 終助詞 し.

なし itself goes back to a classical Japanese adjective and is fossilized in modern Japanese as a noun. Its antonym is あり.

Similar phrases include

- 人でなし brutal, not human
- ろくでなし bum, good for nothing

Answer (score 1):

わけでなし *is* the same thing as わけではないし, yes.
It is true as pointed out by Eddie Kal that なし also has another meaning with roots in classical Japanese, but in this context, it's just a shortened version of ないし.

Comment: Hello @Daniel, welcome to Japanese Stackexchange! If you are not sure of something but want to contribute, it is usually safer to leave a comment rather than an answer. I encourage you to keep participating in the site.

Comment: Hi @jarmanso7, thank you for the heads-up! It seems I need at least 50 reputation to leave a comment (except for my own answers, it seems), so you might see another few answers from me that might be better suited as comments until I reach that amount.

Comment: A good way to build up your reputation besides answering is posting questions. Votes on questions also generate points.